# How to bind Time to paragraph?

Tags: xml, file, indexing, data-structures

I am working on some application that should bind time to each paragraph of any text (UTF-8).

So it should be kinda of index file that we can navigate from one paragraph to another.

And here I got stuck with an  index file structure...

I guessed to use some XML

```
<paragraph start="00:00:05">
CHAPTER I
</paragraph>
<paragraph start="00:00:08">
Down the Rabbit-Hole
</paragraph>

<paragraph start="00:00:11">
Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, `and what is the use of a book,' thought Alice `without pictures or conversation?'
</paragraph>
```

Basically I have to keep the list of Time and some Text Tags (in order to find and select the Paragraph).

My current solution is to create custom object ([which is Dictionary in fact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056098/how-can-i-serialize-an-object-with-a-dictionarystring-object-property)) and then save it via [Binary Writer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759604/using-binarywriter-on-an-object) and when I read it after this I will deserialize it.

But I am not sure if technically that approach is correct one.

And here are my questions:

1. How many text I have to keep to find a Paragraph?
2. Is there other better structure than XML to realize this thing?

Any clues?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand your question here.

Comment: @lc. I should scroll the text based on time from one part of text to another one. I am going to use a Paragraph like a minimum entity to scroll. I have to bind the time to each Paragraph. Imagine I have some text like this http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rgs/alice-table.html and I have to build some HELP file (perhaps some sort of INDEX file) that will keep the time for each text entities and the text tags so I can find this text. And I need to find correct technical solution for that task. Which data structure  I have to use for this?